# Pilsner racking before bottling

Tags: process, racking, pilsner

I`m brewing a pilsner at slightly higher temperature levels and has been two and a half weeks.

Can I rack and then bottle if my hydrometer reading are stable?
Or should I rack and then store in fridge for extended period before bottling?

Answer (score 2):

I'd rack it into a secondary for the sake of cleanliness in the final product.  Especially if you were to coldcrash it before bottling.   Cheers and best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I just made a Czech Pilsner at a little higher temp.  Once it finished fermenting I racked it off the trub into an sanitized secondary that would fit into my frig.  I let it get very cold, then added gelatin to further clear the Pilsner.  I let it sit for a week or so in the frig, it got very clear. At that point I racked it into a keg and I let it lager for a few weeks in the cold frig. The result is a very clear crisp Pilsner, with a creamy head, delicious.  This worked well for me, you may consider the same.